# More columns together in one column beneath one another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my structure of table in my SQL Server 2008 database:

```
╔════╦═════╦═════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ OD1 ║ OD2 ║ OD3 ║
╠════╬═════╬═════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ ž1  ║ ž2  ║ ž3  ║
║  2 ║ c1  ║ c2  ║ c3  ║
║ 15 ║ a1  ║ a2  ║ a3  ║
║ 24 ║ b1  ║ b2  ║ b3  ║
╚════╩═════╩═════╩═════╝
```

I would like to get columns together in one column and beneath one another like this--

```
╔════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ XXX ║
╠════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ ž1  ║
║  1 ║ ž2  ║
║  1 ║ ž3  ║
║  2 ║ c1  ║
║  . ║ .   ║
║  . ║ .   ║
║  . ║ .   ║
║ 24 ║ b2  ║
║ 24 ║ b3  ║
╚════╩═════╝
```

I have an unknown number of columns in one table. I just need this kind of representation for single row that I would connect that with my drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, OD1 NVARCHAR(10), OD2 NVARCHAR(10), OD3 NVARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
( 1 , N'ž1'   , N'ž2'   , N'ž3' ),
( 2 , N'c1'   , N'c2'   , N'c3' ),
(15 , N'a1'   , N'a2'   , N'a3' ),
(24 , N'b1'   , N'b2'   , N'b3' )
```

### Query

```
SELECT ID , XXX
FROM @TABLE t
 UNPIVOT (xxx FOR N IN (OD1, OD2, OD3))up
```

### Result

```
╔════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ XXX ║
╠════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ ž1  ║
║  1 ║ ž2  ║
║  1 ║ ž3  ║
║  2 ║ c1  ║
║  2 ║ c2  ║
║  2 ║ c3  ║
║ 15 ║ a1  ║
║ 15 ║ a2  ║
║ 15 ║ a3  ║
║ 24 ║ b1  ║
║ 24 ║ b2  ║
║ 24 ║ b3  ║
╚════╩═════╝
```